# Php 8.2 curl extension not working windows + mamp

Tags: mamp, php-curl, mamp-pro, php-8.2

I don't get the curl extension working for php 8.2. Im using MAMP PRO (latest version) on windows. For php 8.1 it worked. I tried with php 8.2.1 and 8.2.2.

What I tried:

- Uncomment php_curl.dll in ini
- Try other curl versions
- A lot of google searches
- Add possible missing files to windows system32 folder
- Try if uncommenting other extensions results that they are available, which is the case. Its only curl failing

But nothing helped.Ofcourse after every attempt I restarted the server and the terminal to check if the extension is added.

The error im receiving is ] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl.dll' (tried: C:/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.1/ext\php_curl.dll (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden), C:/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.1/ext
\php_php_curl.dll.dll (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden)) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1):

Curl extension need libcrypto-3-x64.dll and libssl-3-x64.dll not libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, Update this dll.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. To solve this you have to add php to System Path.
Win+R > sysdm.cpl > Advanced Tab > Environment Variables
In System Variables double click "Path" and add New. For me I put "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.2.2"

Answer (score -1):

i have same problem but i just install laragon and it's working again